# Spherical Triangle: Derive law of sine

Tags: vector-analysis, spherical-geometry

Prove the law of sines for the spherical triangle PQR on surface of sphere.

**BACKGROUND**

Suppose we have a sphere of radius 1.  Let vectors $\vec{A}$, $\vec{B}$, and $\vec{C}$ be drawn from the center of the sphere, point O, to points P, Q, and R, on the surface of the sphere, respectively.

[image: spherical triangle]

Use this already proven identity:

$|(\vec{A}\times \vec{B}) \times (\vec{A}\times\vec{C})| = |(\vec{B}\times\vec{C})\times (\vec{B}\times\vec{A})| = |(\vec{C}\times\vec{A})\times (\vec{C}\times\vec{B})|$

to prove the law of sines for the spherical triangle PQR on surface of sphere.

**STEP LAST**:  skipping to the end of proof...

therefore:

$\Large \frac{\sin P}{\sin p} = \frac{\sin Q}{\sin q} = \frac{\sin R}{\sin r}$

which is the law of sines for spherical triangles.

(From "Schuam's outlines: Vector Analysis, second edition", Lipschutz et. al., 2009, 1959, page 37, problem 2.51)

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**: angle is defined as $\Large \theta = \frac{s}{r}$  when the radius ($r=1$) for case of unit sphere, the angle is equal to the arc length, $\Large \theta = s$

Thus, arc length "r" is named after spherical angle "R" because its on the opposite side of spherical triangle, and is identical to "regular angle" $\angle AOB$).

Arc length "q" is named after spherical angle "Q", and is identical to "regular angle" $\angle AOC$

$\angle AOB = r$

$\angle AOC = q$

$|\vec{A}X\vec{B}| = AB\sin (\angle AOB)  =  AB\sin (r)$

$|\vec{A}X\vec{C}| = AC\sin (\angle AOC)  =  AB\sin (q)$

The length of vectors $\vec{A}$, $\vec{B}$, and $\vec{C}$ is equal to one, because the tail starts at the orgin O and the head of the vector ends on the unit sphere.  Thus:

$|\vec{A}| = 1$

$|\vec{B}| = 1$

$|\vec{C}| = 1$

Thus:

$|\vec{A} \times \vec{B}| = \sin (r)$

$|\vec{A} \times \vec{C}| = \sin (q)$

Next, if you flatten the spherical triangle and take the cross product of the two arc sides with angle P in the middle you have:

$|(\vec{A} \times \vec{B}) \times (\vec{A} \times \vec{C})| = |\vec{A}\times\vec{B}|~|\vec{A}\times\vec{C}|~sin(P)$

$|(\vec{A} \times \vec{B}) \times (\vec{A} \times \vec{C})| = \sin (r) \sin (q) \sin(P)$